# Extracting index second part by calling the first part

Tags: python

**Here is a part of output of our program. In this output i want to extract "M. Abrar Hussain" by calling its first index part "Name:" and for rest of the output part, so i want the solution for this if it is possible.Whoosh Library is used for indexing in python so this library might help.**

```
['Name: M. Abrar Hussain  ', 'GPA: 3.5  ', 'Skills: Python, Laravel  ', 'Experience: 3 years ']
```

Comment: This is unclear, what is the expected output? and what have you tried to archive it?

Comment: i am working on a project CV Screening using python. so in Resume i want to extract the name of the applicant by calling just "Name:" part. In this output i used a simple resume with only Name, GPA, Skills and Experience and store in an array by breaking the lines. means index[0] is name index[1] is GPA and so on. so all i want is that by calling the first in the index i want the very next part in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this into a dictionary like this:

```
split_lst = [i.split(': ',1 ) for i in lst]
d = { a : b.rstrip() for a,b in split_lst }
```

The dictionary look like this:

```
{'Name': 'M. Abrar Hussain',
'GPA': '3.5',
'Skills': 'Python, Laravel',
'Experience': '3 years'}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
d["Name"]
```

to get "M. Abrar Hussain  "

Notes:

- Using split(': ',1) is important in case string contains more than one ': '
- rstrip is used to remove trailing spaces from the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['Name: M. Abrar Hussain  ', 'GPA: 3.5  ', 'Skills: Python, Laravel  ', 'Experience: 3 years ']
for item in my_list:
    x=item.split(':')[0].strip()
    y=item.split(':')[1].strip()
    my_map[x]=y
print(my_map)
print(my_map['Name'])
```

The above code should result in below as expected:

```
{'Experience': '3 years', 'Name': 'M. Abrar Hussain', 'GPA': '3.5', 'Skills': 'Python, Laravel'}
M. Abrar Hussain
```

You can store the above output in a dictionary or another list as you like.

Comment: this little bit helpful but not my desired answer b/c i want to extract the name of applicant by calling the "Name:".

Comment: Check the edited code now, that should do what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of ":" character and based on that slice the string and use strip function to eliminate the whitespaces

```
candidate = ['Name: M. Abrar Hussain  ', 'GPA: 3.5  ', 'Skills: Python, Laravel  ', 'Experience: 3 years ']

record = {}

for field in candidate:
    index = field.index(':')
    field_name = field[:index].strip()
    value=field[index+1:].strip()
    record[field_name]=value

field_input = input("Enter the field name")
print(record[field_name])
```

Output

```
M. Abrar Hussain
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to print out the whole field, using

```
applicant=['Name: M. Abrar Hussain  ', 'GPA: 3.5  ', 'Skills: Python, Laravel  ', 'Experience: 3 years ']

print(applicant[0])
```

will print out the name `Name: M. Abrar Hussain`

If you want to get just the actual value (by I assume the content after the :), you can use the split method print out the field

```
applicant=['Name: M. Abrar Hussain  ', 'GPA: 3.5  ', 'Skills: Python, Laravel  ', 'Experience: 3 years ']

def GetField(index):
    print(applicant[index].split(':')[1])

GetField(0)

# Output:
# M. Abrar Hussain
```

You should consider a class or a dictionary over an array though, because arrays don't have any way to identify a field besides an index.